# Smith normal form of matrix over $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: matrices, integers, smith-normal-form

I was wondering if someone could help me find the Smith normal form of the matrix A over $\Bbb Z$ defined as follows:

$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 & 81\\
1 & 4 & 16 & 64 & 256\\
1 & 5 & 25 & 125 & 625\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Clearly this is the same as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4\\
1 & 3 & 3^2 & 3^3 & 3^4\\
1 & 4 & 4^2 & 4^3 & 4^5\\
1 & 5 & 5^2 & 5^3 & 5^4\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Is there some "trick" I am unaware of? Through row and column operations I just get stuck at a matrix looking like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a trick, but there's definitely a lemma you can prove. If you try to do induction you will see that you can force a 1 in one corner and a 4x4 in the other that is "almost" a Vandermonde matrix. Pretending that there is no trouble seems to get you things that keep looking "almost" like Vandermonde matrices but you get (predictable!) spare factors hanging around everywhere. I'm not sure if proving this lemma is more efficient than just brute-forcing the 5x5 case, though; it seems like quite a bit of bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invariance of Fitting ideals probably helps. The matrix and some of its submatrices are 'Vandermonde' matrices so their determinants are easy to calculate.

I think the SNF is $\mathrm{diag}(0!,1!,2!,3!,4!)$, a pattern that generalises with n instead of 5. We can show this sort of inductively, using that such a matrix has determinant $1!2!\cdots(n-1)!$. Please ask if you want more details.

Edit with full details:

The result on Vandermonde determinants can be found on Wikipedia. The easiest way to prove it is to work in $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$, note that setting $X_i = X_j$ gives a zero determinant, so by the factor the lcm of these terms, $\prod_{i<j}(X_j-X_i)$ divides the determinant. Note that so far this works for any k x k submatrix of a Vandermonde matrix, where we replace $X_1,...,X_n$ with the appropriate subset of size k. Comparing degrees, we get for the whole matrix that the determinant is actually equal to $\prod_{i<j}(X_j-X_i)$.

So in our case, where we set $X_i = i$, the determinant is  $\prod_{i<j}(j-i)$ =  $\prod_{j}(j-1)!$.
And any k x k submatrix has determinant a multiple of  $\prod_{i<j}(a_j-a_i)$, for some $\{a_1,...,a_k\} \subset \{1,...,n\}$. I claim this is a multiple of  $\prod_{j=1}^{k}(j-1)!$. Indeed let $p$ be a prime dividing the latter. Let $a$ be the largest number such that $p^a < k$. Note by the pigeonhole principle some pair, wlog  $a_k,a_{k-1}$, has difference a multiple of $p^a$. Discard $a_k$ and make the same argumement with $k \mapsto k-1$. Once p^a = k, replace a with a-1 and make the same argument, etc. I haven't explained this well but this process gives you distinct pairs from the $a_i$'s the product of whose differences is a multiple of p with the same multiplicity as in the prime factorisation of $\prod_{j=1}^{k}(j-1)!$.
Therefore applying for each prime factor, we get that $\prod_{j=1}^{k}(j-1)!$ divides $\prod_{i<j}(a_j-a_i)$ and hence the determinant of the k x k submatrix, as we wanted to show. And if the k x k submatrix is the top-left one, we have equality.

So the Fitting ideals are $\text{Fit}_k = (\prod_{j=1}^{k}(j-1)!)$, and so $d_1...d_k = \prod_{j=1}^{k}(j-1)!$. From here we deduce the invariant factors $d_k = (k-1)!$ for each $k$.

Comment: More details would be great. I am also curious if there are any ways to reduce it to Smith normal form without using Vandermonde? I see brute force is mentioned above, but I have a hard time seing how to do that without reducing the 4 last rows to just zeros.

Comment: I've edited to give what I think is a full proof

Comment: I doubt there's a 'nice' solution without using the Vandermonde determinant result, since this is the main way in which Vandermonde matrices are nice

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time @Danny Duberstein ! It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$P := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 3 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then
$$P A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 15 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 12 & 50 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 60 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 15 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 6 & 25 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} =: DQ.$$
Now since $P$ and $Q$ are unimodular matrices by inspection, it follows that $D$ is the Smith normal form of $A$.

This should generalize nicely to higher values of $n$: if $P$ is the matrix whose $i,j$ element is $(-1)^{i+j} \binom{i-1}{j-1}$, then the $i,j$ element of $PA$ will be $(\Delta^{i-1} x^{j-1}) |_{x = 1}$, which is equal to 0 if $i > j$; equal to $(i-1)!$ if $i = j$; and divisible by $(i-1)!$ if $i < j$.  Therefore, we will again be able to get a similar factorization $PA = DQ$ where $D$ is diagonal with $D_{ii} = (i-1)!$; and $Q$ is upper triangular with 1 on the diagonal and therefore unimodular.

Comment: In fact, it looks like the entries of $Q$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.  So, using that $P^{-1}$ is the Pascal triangle matrix, my guess would be that the relation $A = P^{-1} D Q$ reduces exactly to the identity $x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) x^{\underline k} = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) k! \binom{x}{k}$.